# Failed to build numpy ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-base

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Hi i want to install numpy version 1.18.1 for my old project which is running in another system but when I am trying to run the requirement for numpy 1.18.1 it is giving error below error . there is no such file like pyproject.toml in project.

command  `python3 -m pip install numpy==1.18.1`

**===> I want only this specific version of numpy in my project . .**

```
 [end of output]


  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects



  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/multiarray/shape.c
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalarapi.c: In function ‘scalar_value’:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalarapi.c:74:13: warning: ‘PyUnicode_AsUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     74 |             return (void *)PyUnicode_AS_DATA(scalar);
        |             ^~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                   from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalarapi.c:2:
  /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
    580 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
        |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalarapi.c:135:13: warning: ‘PyUnicode_AsUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    135 |             return (void *)PyUnicode_AS_DATA(scalar);
        |             ^~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                   from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalarapi.c:2:
  /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
    580 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
        |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalarapi.c: In function ‘PyArray_DescrFromScalar’:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalarapi.c:574:13: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    574 |             descr->elsize = PyUnicode_GET_DATA_SIZE(sc);
        |             ^~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                   from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalarapi.c:2:
  /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
    446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
        |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalarapi.c:574:13: warning: ‘PyUnicode_AsUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    574 |             descr->elsize = PyUnicode_GET_DATA_SIZE(sc);
        |             ^~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                   from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalarapi.c:2:
  /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
    580 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
        |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalarapi.c:574:13: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    574 |             descr->elsize = PyUnicode_GET_DATA_SIZE(sc);
        |             ^~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                   from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalarapi.c:2:
  /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
    446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
        |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/multiarray/temp_elide.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/multiarray/typeinfo.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src: In function ‘unicodetype_repr’:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:475:5: warning: ‘PyUnicode_AsUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    475 |     ip = dptr = Py@Name@_AS_@NAME@(self);
        |     ^~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                   from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
    580 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
        |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:476:5: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    476 |     len = Py@Name@_GET_SIZE(self);
        |     ^~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                   from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
    446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
        |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:476:5: warning: ‘PyUnicode_AsUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    476 |     len = Py@Name@_GET_SIZE(self);
        |     ^~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                   from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
    580 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
        |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:476:5: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    476 |     len = Py@Name@_GET_SIZE(self);
        |     ^~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                   from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
    446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
        |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:481:5: warning: ‘PyUnicode_FromUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    481 |     new = Py@Name@_From@Name@@extra@(ip, len);
        |     ^~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                   from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:551:42: note: declared here
    551 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject*) PyUnicode_FromUnicode(
        |                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src: In function ‘unicodetype_str’:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:475:5: warning: ‘PyUnicode_AsUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    475 |     ip = dptr = Py@Name@_AS_@NAME@(self);
        |     ^~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                   from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
    580 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
        |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:476:5: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    476 |     len = Py@Name@_GET_SIZE(self);
        |     ^~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                   from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
    446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
        |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:476:5: warning: ‘PyUnicode_AsUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    476 |     len = Py@Name@_GET_SIZE(self);
        |     ^~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                   from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
    580 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
        |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:476:5: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    476 |     len = Py@Name@_GET_SIZE(self);
        |     ^~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                   from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
    446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
        |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:481:5: warning: ‘PyUnicode_FromUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    481 |     new = Py@Name@_From@Name@@extra@(ip, len);
        |     ^~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                   from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:551:42: note: declared here
    551 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject*) PyUnicode_FromUnicode(
        |                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/multiarray/usertypes.c
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src: In function ‘gentype_reduce’:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:1849:9: warning: ‘PyUnicode_AsUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   1849 |         buffer = PyUnicode_AS_DATA(self);
        |         ^~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                   from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
    580 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
        |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:1850:9: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   1850 |         buflen = PyUnicode_GET_DATA_SIZE(self);
        |         ^~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                   from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
    446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
        |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:1850:9: warning: ‘PyUnicode_AsUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   1850 |         buflen = PyUnicode_GET_DATA_SIZE(self);
        |         ^~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                   from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
    580 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
        |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:1850:9: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   1850 |         buflen = PyUnicode_GET_DATA_SIZE(self);
        |         ^~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                   from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
    446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
        |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src: In function ‘float_arrtype_hash’:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3311:27: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘_Py_HashDouble’
   3311 |     return _Py_HashDouble((double) ((Py@name@ScalarObject *)obj)->obval);
        |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |                           |
        |                           double
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:77,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/pyhash.h:10:38: note: expected ‘PyObject *’ {aka ‘struct _object *’} but argument is of type ‘double’
     10 | PyAPI_FUNC(Py_hash_t) _Py_HashDouble(PyObject *, double);
        |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3311:12: error: too few arguments to function ‘_Py_HashDouble’
   3311 |     return _Py_HashDouble((double) ((Py@name@ScalarObject *)obj)->obval);
        |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:77,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/pyhash.h:10:23: note: declared here
     10 | PyAPI_FUNC(Py_hash_t) _Py_HashDouble(PyObject *, double);
        |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src: In function ‘cfloat_arrtype_hash’:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3319:31: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘_Py_HashDouble’
   3319 |     hashreal = _Py_HashDouble((double)
        |                               ^~~~~~~~
        |                               |
        |                               double
   3320 |             (((PyC@name@ScalarObject *)obj)->obval).real);
        |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:77,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/pyhash.h:10:38: note: expected ‘PyObject *’ {aka ‘struct _object *’} but argument is of type ‘double’
     10 | PyAPI_FUNC(Py_hash_t) _Py_HashDouble(PyObject *, double);
        |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3319:16: error: too few arguments to function ‘_Py_HashDouble’
   3319 |     hashreal = _Py_HashDouble((double)
        |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:77,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/pyhash.h:10:23: note: declared here
     10 | PyAPI_FUNC(Py_hash_t) _Py_HashDouble(PyObject *, double);
        |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3325:31: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘_Py_HashDouble’
   3325 |     hashimag = _Py_HashDouble((double)
        |                               ^~~~~~~~
        |                               |
        |                               double
   3326 |             (((PyC@name@ScalarObject *)obj)->obval).imag);
        |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:77,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/pyhash.h:10:38: note: expected ‘PyObject *’ {aka ‘struct _object *’} but argument is of type ‘double’
     10 | PyAPI_FUNC(Py_hash_t) _Py_HashDouble(PyObject *, double);
        |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3325:16: error: too few arguments to function ‘_Py_HashDouble’
   3325 |     hashimag = _Py_HashDouble((double)
        |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:77,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/pyhash.h:10:23: note: declared here
     10 | PyAPI_FUNC(Py_hash_t) _Py_HashDouble(PyObject *, double);
        |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src: In function ‘longdouble_arrtype_hash’:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3311:27: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘_Py_HashDouble’
   3311 |     return _Py_HashDouble((double) ((Py@name@ScalarObject *)obj)->obval);
        |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |                           |
        |                           double
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:77,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/pyhash.h:10:38: note: expected ‘PyObject *’ {aka ‘struct _object *’} but argument is of type ‘double’
     10 | PyAPI_FUNC(Py_hash_t) _Py_HashDouble(PyObject *, double);
        |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3311:12: error: too few arguments to function ‘_Py_HashDouble’
   3311 |     return _Py_HashDouble((double) ((Py@name@ScalarObject *)obj)->obval);
        |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:77,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/pyhash.h:10:23: note: declared here
     10 | PyAPI_FUNC(Py_hash_t) _Py_HashDouble(PyObject *, double);
        |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src: In function ‘clongdouble_arrtype_hash’:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3319:31: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘_Py_HashDouble’
   3319 |     hashreal = _Py_HashDouble((double)
        |                               ^~~~~~~~
        |                               |
        |                               double
   3320 |             (((PyC@name@ScalarObject *)obj)->obval).real);
        |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:77,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/pyhash.h:10:38: note: expected ‘PyObject *’ {aka ‘struct _object *’} but argument is of type ‘double’
     10 | PyAPI_FUNC(Py_hash_t) _Py_HashDouble(PyObject *, double);
        |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3319:16: error: too few arguments to function ‘_Py_HashDouble’
   3319 |     hashreal = _Py_HashDouble((double)
        |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:77,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/pyhash.h:10:23: note: declared here
     10 | PyAPI_FUNC(Py_hash_t) _Py_HashDouble(PyObject *, double);
        |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3325:31: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘_Py_HashDouble’
   3325 |     hashimag = _Py_HashDouble((double)
        |                               ^~~~~~~~
        |                               |
        |                               double
   3326 |             (((PyC@name@ScalarObject *)obj)->obval).imag);
        |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:77,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/pyhash.h:10:38: note: expected ‘PyObject *’ {aka ‘struct _object *’} but argument is of type ‘double’
     10 | PyAPI_FUNC(Py_hash_t) _Py_HashDouble(PyObject *, double);
        |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3325:16: error: too few arguments to function ‘_Py_HashDouble’
   3325 |     hashimag = _Py_HashDouble((double)
        |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:77,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/pyhash.h:10:23: note: declared here
     10 | PyAPI_FUNC(Py_hash_t) _Py_HashDouble(PyObject *, double);
        |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src: In function ‘half_arrtype_hash’:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3341:27: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘_Py_HashDouble’
   3341 |     return _Py_HashDouble(npy_half_to_double(((PyHalfScalarObject *)obj)->obval));
        |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |                           |
        |                           double
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:77,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/pyhash.h:10:38: note: expected ‘PyObject *’ {aka ‘struct _object *’} but argument is of type ‘double’
     10 | PyAPI_FUNC(Py_hash_t) _Py_HashDouble(PyObject *, double);
        |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3341:12: error: too few arguments to function ‘_Py_HashDouble’
   3341 |     return _Py_HashDouble(npy_half_to_double(((PyHalfScalarObject *)obj)->obval));
        |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:77,
                   from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
  /usr/include/python3.10/pyhash.h:10:23: note: declared here
     10 | PyAPI_FUNC(Py_hash_t) _Py_HashDouble(PyObject *, double);
        |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src: In function ‘longdouble_arrtype_hash’:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3312:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   3312 | }
        | ^
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src: In function ‘float_arrtype_hash’:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3312:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   3312 | }
        | ^
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src: In function ‘half_arrtype_hash’:
  numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3342:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   3342 | }
        | ^
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/multiarray/vdot.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/umath/loops.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/umath/ufunc_object.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/umath/umathmodule.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/multiarray/number.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/umath/reduction.c
  numpy/core/src/umath/loops.c.src: In function ‘PyUFunc_On_Om’:
  numpy/core/src/umath/loops.c.src:363:9: warning: ‘PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    363 |         result = PyEval_CallObject(tocall, arglist);
        |         ^~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:130,
                   from numpy/core/src/umath/loops.c.src:7:
  /usr/include/python3.10/ceval.h:17:43: note: declared here
     17 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.9) PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(
        |                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/umath/scalarmath.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/multiarray/nditer_templ.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/multiarray/flagsobject.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/multiarray/getset.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_complex.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/npymath/halffloat.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/common/npy_longdouble.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/multiarray/nditer_api.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/common/array_assign.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/common/ucsnarrow.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/common/mem_overlap.c
  numpy/core/src/common/ucsnarrow.c: In function ‘PyUnicode_FromUCS4’:
  numpy/core/src/common/ucsnarrow.c:139:9: warning: ‘PyUnicode_FromUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    139 |         ret = (PyUnicodeObject *)PyUnicode_FromUnicode((Py_UNICODE*)buf,
        |         ^~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046,
                   from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                   from numpy/core/src/common/ucsnarrow.c:4:
  /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:551:42: note: declared here
    551 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject*) PyUnicode_FromUnicode(
        |                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/common/ufunc_override.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/common/numpyos.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/umath/extobj.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/umath/cpuid.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/umath/ufunc_type_resolution.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/umath/override.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/multiarray/mapping.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/umath/matmul.c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/umath/clip.c
  error: Command "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/umath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.10 -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath -c build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.o -MMD -MF build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.o.d -std=c99" failed with exit status 1
```